# PostgreSQL planner doesn't want to use bloom index for boolean columns

Tags: postgresql

I created a bloom index, and it turns out that PostgreSQL's query planner just doesn't want to use the index for `boolean`.

Here is my test setup:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS bloom;

-- Adapt bloom index to boolean type
DROP OPERATOR CLASS IF EXISTS bloom_boolean_ops USING bloom;
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS bloom_boolean_ops
DEFAULT FOR TYPE boolean USING bloom AS
OPERATOR  1  = (boolean, boolean),
FUNCTION  1  hashchar;

-- Do the same, but for uuid type
-- This is needed to just demonstrate that this way of defining custom operator classes
-- works for other types, but doesn't work for boolean.
DROP OPERATOR CLASS IF EXISTS bloom_uuid_ops USING bloom;
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS bloom_uuid_ops
DEFAULT FOR TYPE uuid USING bloom AS
OPERATOR  1  = (uuid, uuid),
FUNCTION  1  uuid_hash;

CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    flag boolean NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_tbl (id, flag) VALUES
('e5526344-669c-46ba-aece-8fbc82007161', true),
('b25aefdf-2aba-4e5a-83c3-ec2da3b934ac', false);

CREATE INDEX test_bloom_idx ON test_tbl USING bloom (flag, id);

SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;

-- Try the boolean column. For some reason, the query planner ignores the index.
EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM test_tbl WHERE flag = TRUE;
 -- Seq Scan on test_tbl  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000001.02 rows=1 width=4)
 --   Filter: flag

-- Try the uuid column. Now it works fine.
EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM test_tbl WHERE id = 'e5526344-669c-46ba-aece-8fbc82007161';
-- Bitmap Heap Scan on test_tbl  (cost=8.02..12.03 rows=1 width=4)
--   Recheck Cond: (id = 'e5526344-669c-46ba-aece-8fbc82007161'::uuid)
--   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_bloom_idx  (cost=0.00..8.02 rows=1 width=0)
--         Index Cond: (id = 'e5526344-669c-46ba-aece-8fbc82007161'::uuid)
```

So as illustrated above, the query planner chooses to use index for searching `uuid`, but it just ignores it if the column happens to be `boolean`.

Also boolean expression indexes (like `CREATE INDEX ... ((column = value));`) are broken in the same way.

I've already tried:

- Split a multi-column index to individual single-column indexes (although it doesn't make make a lot of sense with bloom).
- Cast `boolean` to `integer`. It works, but queries are not friendly to the ORM that I use. So this is not an option for me.
- Use different hash functions: `hashint2`, `hashint4`, `hashchar("char")` for the operator class. No effect.

Any suggestions?

(and yeah, I'm aware of partial indexes, they are not quite what I want)

Comment: Indexing a boolean column rarely makes sense as typically the condition will only reduce the result by 50%. If you have a different distribution (e.g. only 10% `true` values), then using a filtered index typically is more efficient, e.g. `create index on test_tbl (id) where flag;`

Comment: Indexing by 1 boolean value isn't good, but a combination of 4 boolean flags reduces the result by 86.5% (assuming uniform of flags).

Comment: Well, you example only shows a single boolean. If you want to index multiple columns, then show us the plan when using multiple columns. In that case you probably want to create [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) on those columns

Comment: Partial indexes are possible, but PostgreSQL is bad in combining multiple indexes. For bloom, it is usually more beneficial to combine many columns (including booleans) into 1 wide index. And also, in case of bloom index, multiple small indexes will probably take more space than 1 wide index. 

So I really want to at least try and measure a big wide multi-column index.
Not a bunch of partial indexes.

Comment: I just didn't want to expose code that I'm working on because it is not open source. So I created a minimal example to demonstrate that any boolean column is ignored. In reality, I have a large and wide table with a lot of columns, some of them happen to be booleans. If I combine many indexed columns in the same query, then the planner ignores index for booleans, but uses the index for the remaining columns.

Comment: You drop your operator classes in the wrong order, so that your example doesn't work out of the box.  But once I fix that, I can reproduce it but don't know why it happens.

Comment: I fixed the example, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, B-Tree indexes do work, but they are not quite suitable for me (more than 10 searchable columns, mostly independent, and appear in different combinations in search queries). A bloom index performs much better in my case. The only problem is it doesn't work with flags, so I just wanted to fix that specific problem, not change the index type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the optimizer changes the query condition for a `boolean` like this:

```
 Seq Scan on test_tbl
   Filter: flag
```

Since the condition is no longer of the form `expression = constant`, the bloom index isn't used.

You can force the optimizer to retain the original shape of the condition by using a subquery:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF) SELECT 1 FROM test_tbl WHERE flag = (SELECT TRUE);

                QUERY PLAN                 
-------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test_tbl
   Recheck Cond: (flag = $0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Result
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_bloom_idx
         Index Cond: (flag = $0)
(6 rows)
```

But I guess that your Obfuscating Rewrite Mapper won't be happy to generate such queries either.

One could consider an implicit type cast from `boolean` to `integer`, but you cannot do that since there already is a (non-implicit) such type cast, so you'd have to delete that first. Messing with the catalogs in that fashion is not what I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. Also, I've found hacks for B-tree and Hash operator classes in the PostgreSQL's optimizer source code. So this thing would work for B-tree and Hash, but not other index types. So GIN, GiST and BRIN indexes also won't work on boolean columns.